# Can docker check if a CIFS volume is offline?

Tags: docker

The scenario is a machine that has some network connection issues. That means that the CIFS volume container sometimes become unavailable. If I restart it when the network is working, everything works fine again.

The question is if docker provides a way to know if a CIFS mounted volume is available or the volume is down. With this feature, for example, I can try to create a cronjob to mount again the volume if unavailable. But only if is unavailable.